# Maximum HTTP GET Method in JSON

Tags: json, gwt, jsonp, http-get

I am doing an HTTP GET with JSONP from GWT..

The URL contains +1000 character.
The problem is the request doesn't reach the server

Do you see the problem here in the length of the HTTP URL? as when I do request the same server with fewer characers (+500 character) I get it working..

BTW, it appears to be IE8-only issue.

Thanks?

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum lenght for IE, but 1000 chars should be fine.  As documented here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/  IE should handle upto 2,083 characters.

In any case: it is recommended to do posts for such large datasets.  POST does not have these limits.

Comment: I don't see a way to make POST work with JSONP (JSONP simply inserts a `script` tag, which the browser fetches by using GET.) So if cross site requests are required, the only possibility I see, would be to split the request.

Comment: You can always create a new page in an iframe that auto-submits a form using post...

Comment: Ok, I think this could work (not sure). Have you tried it? Would be a very interesting solution indeed.